# How to see variables denoted by Greek letters in viscode's interactive window?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm currently using Python3.73 on VSCode. I execute the code on interactive window with Jupiter notebook. The problems are:

1. I can't type Greek letters in notebook cells while I can type them in editor using LaTeX syntax;
2. Even if I copy a Greek letter from somewhere else and paste it in a cell in interactive window and denote it as the name of a variable, I can't find this variable in the interactive data viewer. But I'm sure it's stored somewhere because I can still call it again.

e.g.
[example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWJuF.png)
, but the eigenvalues can't be seen after clicking the
["Show variable in data viewer button"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQHmZ.png)

So how can I type Greek letters in interactive cells directly? and how can I see variables denoted by Greek letters?

Comment: I wouldn't use  Greek letters at all. And the same with any other native letters. Only English (or rather ASCII) `A-Z a-z 0-9 _`

Comment: I agree with you and I usually don't use other letters either. I just hope I can use and see them when I want to. I believe there's a way to do it.

Comment: even if you resolve this on your computer it still can be problem for other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I type Greek letters in interactive cells directly?

Jupyter Notebook can recognize Greek letters, after typing `\alpha`, pressing **Tab**, you'll get `α`, which you can try in [JupyterLab](https://jupyter.org/try). But it's not achievable in VS Code.

Although Greek letters' English name are stored in Jupyter in VS Code, but it couldn't be turned into `α` automatically in VS Code. Furthermore, to [Tab Complete Greek Letters](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/806), the production group **vscode-jupyter** does't have plans on adding this functionality at this time.

> how can I see variables denoted by Greek letters?

The default encoding format is UTF-8. Not only Greek, but also Cyllic and other non-english language can't be shown in Variables Viewer. So there's no way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I was also missing this feature from vscode. Luckily, there is now the `tablatex` extension, that does exactly what you want:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=andyljones.tablatex

[image]

Comment: Oh good. In this day and age, there's *really* no excuse to not support other languages, even and especially in code. Unicode exists for a damn reason -_-.